# Есть ли у меня стилистическая ошибка?

Tags: грамотная-речь, стилистика

> Считают, что это задание, а не жизненная ситуация. Ну и во втором случае всё равно ждут рассуждений автора.

Так я сказал об одном из вопросов, который некоторые хотели закрыть как д/з. Я объяснял собеседнику, почему, на мой взгляд, его таковым считают.

Так вот, товарищ не может успокоиться и утверждает, что *"всё равно"* здесь употреблено *стилистически* неверно, так как оно отсылает к первому случаю (заданию), по его словам. Я под ним подразумеваю синоним *"тоже".*

Я вообще понять не могу, что ему не нравится и почему он так упорно придирается к этим моим словам. Рассудите, пожалуйста, всё ли тут нормально или действительно стилистика нарушена и как.

Скажите, пожалуйста, *понятно, что я подразумеваю под **вторым случаем**?* Прокомментируйте, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Считают, что это задание, а не жизненная ситуация. Ну и во втором
>   случае всё равно ждут рассуждений автора.

В начале второго предложения напрашивается "но и" вместо "ну и". А выражение "ну и ждут рассуждений автора" воспринимается как "поэтому ждут...". Я сам пару раз споткнулся о начало второго предложения, пока понял, что имеется в виду. Не думаю, что такое употребление корректно.

> Скажите, пожалуйста, понятно, что я подразумеваю под вторым случаем?

Да.

Comment: Спасибо большое, grizzly! Рад вас видеть снова! Да, я тоже думал, что может быть лучше "но и". Под "ну и" имел в виду "вдобавок", но согласен, что с "но и" получается близкий смысл и виден переход от первого предложения ко второму. Рад, что понимаете, что я подразумевал под "вторым случаем"! А можете всё-таки сказать, что именно, чтобы до конца убедиться, что вы правильно поняли? Мне это важно.

Comment: (Спасибо.) Под "вторым случаем" здесь можно понимать только "жизненную ситуацию", я уверен.

Comment: А что воспринимается под "вторым случаем" изначально, если не вдумываться?

Comment: @oleedd Я и не вдумываюсь. Порядковый номер определяется очерёдностью следования (упоминания). Если только в контексте явно не был указан другой порядок.

Comment: Спасибо! Да, так и есть!)

Comment: Как можно делить, что первый случай - что это задание, а второй - что это не жизненная ситуация? Они ведь считают так сразу - что это не жизненная ситуация, а задание. И речи не было, что они либо считают, что это задание, либо считают, что это жизненная ситуация. Нет смыслового разделения на случаи, так как в первом предложении описывается единая ситуация. Так, может, слово "случай" использовано некорректно? И всё равно во втором случае у нас "не жизненная ситуация", а воспринять уже нужно без частицы "не". Где логика такого восприятия?

Comment: "Второй случай" здесь можно отнести только к сочетанию "жизненная ситуация" из первого предложения, но тогда возникает _противоречие_: этот "случай" полностью **отрицается** (через "а не") в пользу первого (задание), однако к нему проявляют некое внимание в форме "ожидания рассуждений". Из-за этого совсем неясно, к чему относятся "всё равно" и "ну и".

Comment: @Alex_ander Отнести-то можно. Но корректно ли ссылаться случаями на куски текста? У этого слова совсем другое значение. Я понял, что это просто второй случай, о котором расскажут далее.

Comment: В нашем примере это некорректно (я пояснил, почему), в другом контексте - возможно. "Случай" - не обязательно событие или действие, его достаточно бывает обозначить существительным. Например, оговорено, что вопросы бывают типа "(домашнего) задания" или "жизненной ситуации". В первом случае (= имеет место "домашнее задание") на вопрос не дают ответа, а во втором - помогают.

Comment: Спасибо, что прокомментировали, Александр!

Comment: @Alex_ander Если оговорено, то конечно. Но не ссылаться же так на существительные из предыдущего предложения.

Comment: @oleedd Я, кажется, понял причину недоразумения. Конечно, под "вторым случаем" понимается "[они] считают это жизненной ситуацией". Просто мы все сокращаем формулировку этого случая для краткости.